# Boy and girl live on a world where tech is outlawed, find spaceship and travel to another planet

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, post-apocalyptic

I've been trying to find a book I read as a kid. Its about 2 teens (boy and girl) who live on a world where tech is outlawed by a god the people worship called overseer or overwatcher or overthought I can't remember. But they discover that the god is actually an ancient satellite that effects peoples thoughts. They eventually find and board a spaceship and travel to another planet later turning out to be earth way in the future and they were desendant from the humans that left thousands of years ago. They meet two new species of intelligent creatures. One evolved from rats and the other from bats. That's all I can remember. If anyone knows the book please help. Thank you

Comment: When did you read it? ("as a kid" means nothing to us :-) )

Answer (score 5):

This is the Homecoming Saga by Orson Scott Card. It consists of five books:

1. The Memory of Earth
2. The Call of Earth
3. The Ships of Earth
4. Earthfall
5. Earthborn

Most of what you describe takes place, from memory, in books 4 and 5. See if this brings back memories:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homecoming_Saga

> On Harmony, the colonists established the Oversoul - an artificial intelligence, monitoring the planet with a small army of satellites. It also influences the actions of humans. Though it does not prevent them from doing evil, it keeps their destruction limited by suppressing any thoughts that might lead to things like long-distance travel or instant communication. Thus the technology on Harmony includes basic computers, presumably without advanced Internet capabilities, although the Oversoul was used for basic data transfer, and solar-powered handheld energy weapons, but no cars or even wagons.

The two kids are Nafai (14) and Luet (13) who lead the expedition back to Earth.

Comment: When I saw the original question, I *wondered* if that series might be the one. But I only started to read Book 1 once, very long ago, found it boring, returned it to the library, and never bothered to read any more of the series. So I wasn't sure if one of the later books would be a perfect fit for the details provided; figured I'd let someone with more data try to answer.

Comment: Thanks so much guys

Comment: @Anthonygroves if the answer is correct please accept it by ticking the checkmark on the left of the answer.